# How can I make hostnames accessible?

Tags: networking, wifi, esp8266, lan

I am using the Sonoff-Tasmota firmware to configure ESP-8266 devices for my home automation system.  These devices log onto the WiFi network and obtain IP addresses via DHCP.  The problem is that after they come up on the network they are not accessible to the web browser using their hostname.

I have other devices (like Raspberry Pi and windows PC's) that also use WiFi and DHCP and they can be accessed using their hostnames, so I think the router is working ok.

I have traced the DHCP dialog using Wireshark and I can see the hostname in the request, so I don't know what else to do.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a process listening for incoming connections on port 80 running on the devices you are trying to connect to? You can use [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/book/man.html#man-description) to scan the devices to check for open ports

Answer (score 4):

Try `ping` this device by its hostname.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping bacchus

Envoi d’une requête 'ping' sur bacchus.home [192.168.1.11] avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 192.168.1.11 : octets=32 temps=1 ms TTL=64
```

Also don't forget your network suffix (mine is `.home` as you can see on top), you can find this information with an `ifconfig`/`ipconfig /all` or by reverse-searching your domain name.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping -a 192.168.1.11

Envoi d’une requête 'ping' sur bacchus.home [192.168.1.11] avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 192.168.1.11 : octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=64
```

If the `ping` is successful you can do as @SYS_V says : run `nmap` to be sure the 80 port isn't already occupied.

Comment: It might work even though the ping fails. Devices don't have to react to pings.

Comment: Yes, ping is just to get/resolve the hostname to see how it reacts to the network.